# [Kubuntu 14.04][Eclipse] ADT crashes at button OK from Project properties

Tags: 14.04, java, themes, gtk, crash

Since i upgraded to kubuntu 14.04, my Eclipse crashes at different situations. Mostly i can "simulate" it when going to project properties and press ok. Then it always crashes.

**My system:**

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
```

**My Java:**

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

**My ADT Version:**

```
Android Development Toolkit
Version: 23.0.0.1245622
```

I already tried to add this in *adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/configuration.ini*

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

**Error:**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe049eb1718, pid=5964, tid=140601811232512
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgobject-2.0.so.0+0x19718]  g_object_get_qdata+0x18
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/maddin/core or core.5964
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/maddin/hs_err_pid5964.log
Compiled method (nm)   28866 4166     n 0       org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS::_g_object_get_qdata (native)
 total in heap  [0x00007fe051da6790,0x00007fe051da6af0] = 864
 relocation     [0x00007fe051da68b0,0x00007fe051da68f8] = 72
 main code      [0x00007fe051da6900,0x00007fe051da6ae8] = 488
 oops           [0x00007fe051da6ae8,0x00007fe051da6af0] = 8
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Now, as soon as i change *SystemSettings -> Application Apperance -> GTK -> GTKn-Design* to something else but "oxygen-gtk" this crash doesn't happen anymore.

But the application appearance also is ugly. Beside that i get a lot of errors/warnings like that:

```
(SWT:6148): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_closure_add_invalidate_notifier: assertion 'closure->n_inotifiers < CLOSURE_MAX_N_INOTIFIERS' failed
```

or other GTK warnings from the particular design, not having theme-engine.

Which actually doesn't cause any crahs it seems so far.

---

So i have 3 options:

- accept crashes
- accept warnings (maybe the best choice)
- accept ugly design

What can i do to solve this issue without changing the design settings?

Comment: Sad, nobody even answers. Cant believe i am the only one having this issue.

Comment: You are in no way the only one. You just saved me lots of nerves as no other tip helped. But now I am stuck with the ugly UI as you are...

Comment: One tip: you can decrease the font. Makes it a bit less ugly.

Comment: @zm did it already ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've hit the following bug that is not fixed yet: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=736323 .

Workaround:

1. Find your GTK2 theme config file. For Oxygen it is `/usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`.
2. Edit the theme config file (as root): change `GtkComboBox::appears-as-list` from `1` to `0`.

Comment: This made Comsol Multiphysics stop crashing on Kubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This is still an issue with 14.04... even in 2016.  Thanks for the quick-fix.

Comment: Nice, this this a general fix for numerous Java GTK2 programs; in my case the Android SDK and AVD Managers were constantly crashing

Answer (score 1):

Had the issue with Tizen SDK (java) and it worked after I changed default GtK+ theme[image: kde-gtk-theme]